# Last row not correct / empty rows if entry exists in list

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

**What is my goal:** 
Creating a list of entries with webScapring. The Scraper works fine and creates the list. It checks if a value exists. Only if the value not exists it will add to the list. The list is to be extended continuously.

**Expexted result:** If a value exist in the list it will be skipped. If a value not exist it will be written in the next free line, without free rows.

**Actual result:** It makes for every value which exists an empty line. For example if 4 values still exists, it creates 4 empty rows.

Option Explicit

```
Sub ExposeID()

Dim browser As Object   'Aufnehmen der verwendeten Instanz des Browsers (Internet Explorer)
Dim knotenAst As Object 'Aufnehmen einer HTML Struktur aus dem Browser Dokument
Dim n As Integer
Dim url As String       'Aufnehmen der auszulesenden Adresse

Dim ExposeID As String
Dim letztezeile As Integer
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

Dim ZählerÜbersprungen As Integer
ZählerÜbersprungen = 0
Dim ZählerHinzugefügt As Integer
ZählerHinzugefügt = 0

Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    browser.Visible = False

For n = 0 To 1

    url = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/niedersachsen/oldenburg-oldenburg/haus-kaufen?pagenumber=" & n + 1
    browser.navigate url
    Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    letztezeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set nodeList = browser.document.querySelectorAll(".result-list__listing[data-id]")
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1

Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id")
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("IDs").Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        ZählerÜbersprungen = ZählerÜbersprungen + 1
        Else
          Cells(letztezeile + i + 1, 1) = nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id")
        ZählerHinzugefügt = ZählerHinzugefügt + 1
        End If
    End With
End If

Next i
Next n

Set nodeList = Nothing

i = 0
n = 0

browser.Quit

MsgBox "Es wurden " & ZählerHinzugefügt & " Einträge hinzugefügt." & vbCrLf & "Es wurden " & ZählerÜbersprungen & " Einträge übersprungen.", vbOKOnly

ZählerÜbersprungen = 0
ZählerHinzugefügt = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure but you should add a sheet reference here `Cells(letztezeile + i + 1, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I have only one worksheet. Nevertheless I have added the sheet reference and unfortunately there is  no difference.

Comment: Have you stepped through? If the value is not found `Rng` should be nothing.

Comment: @SJR Yes I stepped through with F8. If the value is not found Rng is nothing. This step works fine. If the value still exists it makes an empty entry, so it skips the line. I think my issue is in the line   `Cells(letztezeile + i + 1, 1) = nodeList.Item(i).getAttribute("data-id")`

Comment: Because its also increases the row-number if no value had been found.

Comment: If it's found all that happens is that `ZählerÜbersprungen` goes up by 1. Not sure what that does, but nothing should be written on the sheet. Perhaps the values you think are found are not?